# Check if the logged in user is an owner of AAD M365 group

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a M365 group in Azure Active Directory.

[image]

Is there a MS graph api to check if the logged in user is an owner of M365 group?

Comment: How is the screenshot relevant to the question? It's a little bit confusing because the screenshot shows App registrations. Not group.

Answer (score 0):

In Graph API you can list the owners of the group

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/owners
```

Or you can get the list of groups that are owned by the user

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ownedObjects/microsoft.graph.group
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/ownedObjects/microsoft.graph.group
```

Resources:

[Group - list owners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[User - list owned objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-ownedobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an M365 Group and assigned an owner:

[image]

Now, I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated the **auth-code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated the **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientId
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, the permissions are displayed like below:

[image]

By using the above token, you can **query the group owner successfully** like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupObjID/owners
```

[image]

I agree with @user2250152, you can also make use of below query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ownedObjects/microsoft.graph.group
```

[image]